# Updating dictionary values using keys and values from lists

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, hash, key-value

I want to be able to index a dictionary and replace its values for particular keys by using keys from within a specific list and writing values to those keys from that list.

**Code**

```
dicty = {"NDS" : 1, "TCT": 2, "ET" : 3, "ACC" : 4,"Ydist" : 5, "Diam" : 6}


tem = ["NDS", "TCT"]
circ = ["ET", "ACC"]
jit = ["Ydist", "Diam"]


def cal_loop(cal_vers):
    if cal_vers == temp_calibration:
        print("DO TEMP CALIBRATION")
        tem_results = [19,30]
        dict_keys = tem
        dicty[[dict_keys][0]] = tem_results[0]
        print(dicty["NDS"])

temp_calibration = 6


cal_loop(temp_calibration)
print(dicty)
```

**Traceback**

[image]

**Desired output**

```
{'NDS': 19, 'TCT': 2, 'ET': 3, 'ACC': 4, 'Ydist': 5, 'Diam': 6}

#I also want to know how to do both keys in the list given e.g.
{'NDS': 19, 'TCT': 30, 'ET': 3, 'ACC': 4, 'Ydist': 5, 'Diam': 6}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tem = ["NDS", "TCT"]
tem_results = [19,30]

for k, v in zip(tem, tem_results):
    dicty[k] = v
```

The issue is with `dicty[[dict_keys][0]] = tem_results[0]`. You have to loop thought the two lists and update the dictionary or instead create a new dictonary and update the existing one using:

```
dicty.update({k: v for k, v in zip(tem, tem_results)})
```